# How to track per-app-version statistic/revenues in AdMobi (Android app)

Tags: android, admob

Is there some way to track which versions of my apps generate which portion of the revenue using the Admob SDK (now integrated to Google Play Services library)? E.g. by sending some custom param with the `AdBuilder`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is that you could create different AdUnits and use different units for each version.